# How to add a number of the order to the redirect URL (2checkout)?

Tags: 2checkout

I set up payments through the payment system 2checkout.com. I have a problem with the redirect URL. I need a redirect to my site after payment. And I need the order number in the redirect URL. But he's not there. How do I add this parameter to a redirect URL?

Comment: example for redirect url and send additional info about product.
 https://secure.2checkout.com/checkout/buy/?return-url=https://your-return-url.com/?your-payment-id=id&return-type=redirect&order-ext-ref=payment-id

you can use return-url parameter to redirect your user after successful payment and order-ext-ref parameter to send external reference of your payment

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the 2checkout documentation for accepted parameters for checkout?

Find 2checkout documentation for all available parameters.
https://knowledgecenter.2checkout.com/Documentation/07Commerce/2Checkout-ConvertPlus/ConvertPlus_URL_parameters

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hosted checkout with using this method `\Twocheckout_Charge::form($params, 'auto');`, then use `"return_url" => 'YOUR-RETURN-URL-HERE'` parameter for redirect on your custom URL after placed an order.

You can also use Order No. or any parameter in return_url e.g: `"return_url" => 'yourdomain.com/order-placed/123',` or `"return_url" => 'yourdomain.com/order-placed?order_id=123',`

Or if you are using Checkout as charge on your own website by using this method: `$charge = \Twocheckout_Charge::auth();` then try this code:

```
if ($charge['response']['responseCode'] == 'APPROVED') 
    {
        $statusMsg = "";
        $statusMsg = '<h2>Thanks for your Order!</h2>';
        $statusMsg .= '<h4>The transaction was successful. Order details are given below:</h4>';
        $statusMsg .= "<p>Response Code: ".$charge['response']['responseCode']."</p>";
        $statusMsg .= "<p>Order ID: ".$charge['response']['orderNumber']."</p>";
        $statusMsg .= "<p>Transaction ID: ".$charge['response']['transactionId']."</p>";
        $statusMsg .= "<p>Order Total: ".$charge['response']['total']." USD</p>";
    }
    else
    {
        $statusMsg = "";
        $statusMsg .= "<p>Transaction Faild. Response Code: ".$charge['response']['responseCode']."</p>";
    }

    REDIRECT HERE: on yourdomain.com/order-placed/$charge['response']['orderNumber']
```